# CSS: Why 2 elements have visual difference in height?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements:

- canvas (supposed to display some 'custom' drawings)
- details div aside (supposed to display text information with details about drawings)

I'd like them to have a thing border and look similar (in height).

```
<canvas #canvas width="900" height="600" class="map">
</canvas>
<div class="operations">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
canvas.map {
  border: black 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
}
div.operations {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Unfortunately, the bottom parts of those 2 elements have borders at different heights.

[image]

Can someone please help understanding why and fix this? Thanks!

P.S. Interestingly, when I put this code to https://jsfiddle.net/seredaom/gz12tjkq/3/ it is operations div that becomes bigger. And in this case, I can correct the height by setting padding for it to 0, but I'd like to keep it at 5 px. That sounds like the problem is the content of the div. But, it has not special formatting, just regular HTML controls with no ANY custom formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause of the difference in height is the padding. The default `box-sizing` is `content-box`, but what you're probably expecting (and what should be the default) is `border-box`.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This brings the heights to 602px and 600px. Seems applying the height using the attribute causes a different behavior than using CSS, at least in Chrome. I'm not sure why. My advice is to move the height to the CSS. If you have no control over it, you can use an `outline` instead of a `border` to avoid the layout change, or use a transparent border on the `div`. Another option is using a `calc` though this all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: As I wrote in another comment, setting 'box-sizing' for .operations to 'border-box' combined with using 'outline' instead of 'border' worked. Though, I don't understand why the border and outline for div work as always properly (600 and 602 px height always), but border for canvas gets bigger when DIV for operations gets bigger...
Stanislav wrote "canvas scales"... so i guess that's why you recommend to use a wrapper div around? I've tried, but it did not seem to help. Could you please suggest HTML and css code for those? Thanks!

Comment: @Budda seems the cause of the discrepancy was the use of the height attribute instead of using CSS. I updated.

Comment: Yeah, this helped.
In fact, I was trying to move height+width to CSS even before posting this, but after that for some reasons graphics inside of the canvas was squeezed. The trick apparently is to keep size in both HTML and CSS.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to achieve the same height you can use outline for canves with box-sizing:content-box and box-sizing: border-box for div.

```css
canvas.map {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  outline: black 1px solid;
}
div.operations {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<canvas #canvas width="900" height="600" class="map">
</canvas>
<div class="operations">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is something I did not know. I got the idea of where to look into it. Though, in your example, the top line of the border of operation div is 1 line lower than canvas's while the bottom one - higher. I've tried to change 'outline' for canvas back to the border.. and interestingly, it does not seem like setting box-sizing to context box made any difference. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The canvas width and height attributes sets boundaries of coordinate system in canvas element itself, which is then displayed in HTML box as content.

If there is difference canvas scales its rendered content to the HTML content box.

So in your case you set .operations **content box** explicitly to has height 600px and padding box is 5px, so you should set same values to .map as well. The canvas height is set 600px by attributes so **content-box** of .map element is sized to canvas and you can set padding-box of .map to same value as .operations.

Comment: If i set padding for .map to 5 then the drawings inside won't be touching the border and that will look ugly (in my scenario). But similar effect (I guess) I could achieve by setting box-sizing to border-box for the .operations. In this case, drawing the border it should 'hide' the fact, that there is a padding... But somehow in this case border around the .operations is 2 pixels shorter than the border around the .map. I've tried to experiment and instead of 'borders' used 'outline'... and magically now those look the same height... Anyone knows why?

Comment: Hi there, my description was more educative then strict how to. There are multiple ways how to make those boxes aligned. If you understand that canvas attributes sets size of .map content and .operations has content size from styles width,height it is easy. I would suggest you to make .operations,.map same https://jsfiddle.net/y0mr6gpj/  Might be more readable for you this way...